# Error downloading file on SF site

Tags: force.com-sites

I'm having trouble downloading file that i've uploaded from the guest user on an sf site. (the file is uploadead by the guest user too)

FYI : it was working and it just stopped recently.

I'm using the link : `href="/xxxx/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/068xxxxxxxxx" target="_blank"`

My result is a blank page with the error : `top.location='https://preprod-xxxxxxxxx.cs129.force.com/ex/errorduringprocessing.jsp'`

The file ContentDocumentLink visibility is set on 'AllUsers'

I'm always using the same code on other org, and it just doesn't work on this one.
The only difference i've seen from older site is the new parameter "default record owner" on the site configuration. (who's set on the administrator)

Do you have any idea?

Thanks for your help,

Louis

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the issue. The link was used by guest users in a public site. ContentDocument was successfully downloaded in sandbox, but the error appeared in production.

In my case the error appeared due to a wrong sharing rule in production: accounts became hidden from the guest users, while they need to have access to the records, associated with the document(accounts in my case) in order to download it. After we'd fixed the rule, the error has dissapeared.